# How to find the fully qualified namespace of a symbol?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

If I have a symbol who's namespace is an alias, like q/w, how can I find its actual namespace, say actual.namespace/w ?

I know that `resolve` will give me the fully qualified var, but I don't know how to get the namespace of a var.

The best I can do is:

```
 (defn fqns [s] (str (get (ns-aliases *ns*) (symbol (namespace s)))))
```

surely there's a simpler way ?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the namespace object of a symbol as shown below (if you want name of ns as string then just call str at the end):

```
(defn fqns [s] (->> (resolve s) meta :ns))
```

Answer (score 2):

The symbol itself has no direct connection to any namespace object; its namespace part is just an interned string. It is only when it's being `resolve`d that this string is treated as the name of an actual namespace in which to look up a Var. (In particular, you can create a symbol `foo/bar` without creating a namespace `foo` or registering `foo` as an alias for a namespace.) Thus, you need to either go through `resolve` or do part of its work yourself.

In the first case, you can say (in recent versions of Clojure; or you can skip the hyphens signifying property access -- instead of `-ns`, use `ns` -- to be backwards compatible)

```
(.. (resolve s) -ns -name)
```

This resolves a Var object, then extracts a reference to its namespace from its `ns` field and finally extracts the symbolic name of the namespace from its `name` field. (Note that the `namespace` and `name` functions wouldn't work, since Vars and namespaces do not implement `clojure.lang.Named`.)

The function from the question text is fine too, although it'll be better to extract the symbol name from the namespace -- `(.-name (get ...))` -- rather than rely on the `toString` representation of namespaces through the use of `str`.

You may also want to add `clojure.lang.Var` and `clojure.lang.Namespace` type hints to avoid reflection in your calls. (If you want them to be faster, or if you need `*warn-on-reflection*` to tweak something else for performance and wish to avoid useless warnings here.)

If you wish to handle the possibility that the namespace does not exist (and return `nil` in that case, in keeping with usual Clojure idiom):

```
(defn fqns
  ([s]
    (fqns (.-name *ns*) s))
  ([ns s]
    (some-> ns
            find-ns
            .-name
            ns-aliases
            (get (symbol (namespace s)))
            .-name)))
```

Or use some `if-let`s in Clojure 1.4 and earlier.